# Date params form issue

Tags: grails, date, groovy

I'm getting some troubles with the tag  and then updating my Date attribute from a model with the params sent.

Here is my tag:

```
    <g:datePicker name="data" value="${controle.data}" precision="month" 
        years="${(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)-70)..Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)}"/>
```

When I println the "params.data" it says "struct", but I can't simply do:

```
model.data = params.data
```

the params comes with params.data_month and params.data_year with the respectives values in String like:

```
[[data:struct], [data_month:1], [data_year:2009]]
```

I tried to do then:

```
model.data = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yyyy").parse("${params.data_month}/${params.data_year}")
```

but it rejects the value, alerting: "*Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Date] for property 'data*'"

```
println model.data
println new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yyyy").parse("${params.data_month}/${params.data_year}")

--shows

2006-01-01 00:00:00.0
Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 BRST 2006
```

Answer (score 1):

> but I can't simply do: model.data =
>   params.data

Why not? Are you getting an exception, or are you just being mislead by outdated documentation? -
This is a feature [since Grails 1.2](http://www.grails.org/1.2+Release+Notes). Conversion to a `Date` type will be performed, automatically.

As for the `SimpleDateFormat` issue, just add a *day*, like so:

```
model.data = new SimpleDateFormat("d/MM/yyyy").parse(
    "1/${params.data_month}/${params.data_year}")
```